# How to login popup windows?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, popupwindow

i'm trying to login this [site](https://en.gamefa.com/) with selenium -python
but i can't .i read another question but i didn't get it.
how can i do it?
this my error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b68Ix.png)
this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.gamefa.com/")
driver.find_element_by_name("loginform").submit()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ModalBoxBody")#.submit()
time.sleep(10)
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_name("log")
elem1.send_keys("mehrdad78")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")
elem2.send_keys("mehrdad78").submit()
```

Comment: `submit()` is for forms. Use `click()` instead.

Comment: i did it few moments ago.but it did not work.

Comment: there is no elements with name `"loginform"`, `"log"`, `"pwd"`

Comment: yes.there are.in login pop up page

Answer (score 0):

**First,** Your screenshot is not giving us enough data about the error. Post the error stack trace which directs to your code.

**Second,** all the items have id. It would be better to use id to find elements.

**Third**, Click does work. Submit doesn't work on buttons. using submit on an element outside a form should throw an exception.

**Fourth,** Use explicit wait instead of sleep.

**Try this**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://en.gamefa.com/")

driver.find_element_by_id("login-form").click()

elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_login3")).send_keys("mehrdad78")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("user_pass3").send_keys("mehrdad78")
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_id("wp-submit3").submit()
```

Comment: looks like the DOM  is changed or I didn't check the login button id first time. I've updated the first login button click code. 
I can see there was an ElementNotVisibleException occurred. I can't see for which element the exception is thrown. Can you find that and attach the stack trace?

Comment: please.check this site:https://www.zoomg.ir/ .this site has sameway login.my problem is that how to login pop up windows in any site?(general way)

Comment: @Mehrdadch
I've run the code in java. It works.
There are differences in two sites pop up. The first site's popup was in the same HTML body. but in the second site, it is in a different frame. You have to switch to the login popup frame first. Then you can enter the username and password. after login, you have to switch back to default content for further tasks.  Generally, most popups are in the same frame so you don't have to switch the frame but usually, you have to switch to the active element for popup modals.

Comment: please send your code.i don't know how to login popup window at all.please help me.